# Is there a contradiction between "set-theoretic" and "formal" definition of "Big-O"?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, landau-notation

- $O(n) = \{n, n^{2}, n^{1000000}, 2^{n}, ...\}$ [[Source A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-%CE%98n-and-on)], [[Source B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations)]
- Say $t_{n} \in O(n)$
- By formal definition $t_{n} \leq k \cdot n$  [[Source C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations)]

But how can this be? Say $t_{n}$ is actually $n^{2}$, then $t_{n} \leq k \cdot n$ is just false. Would it not be more logical to have $t_{n} \geq k \cdot n$ as a formal definition acompanying $O(n)$?

Comment: Your first "definition" isn't really a definition - you're not explaining which functions appear on the right-hand side. It also doesn't appear in any of your sources. The first source mentions that a function which is $O(n)$ is also $O(n^2)$, i.e., $O(n) \subseteq O(n^2)$. The function you list on the right-hand side actually all belong to $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: I don't see what in your sources A and B makes you think that we could write $O(n)=\{n,n^2,\ldots\}$. In general your last definition is the right one (with appropriate quantifiers, namely there exists $k,n_0$ s.t. for all $n>n_0$ ...).

Comment: @Yuval Filmus If $\Omega(n) = \{n, n^{2}, n^{1000000}, 2^{n}, ...\}$ would be a correct (sloppy) equality, what would be $O(n) = ...$?

Comment: It feels like you don't see the difference between $n^k$ and $O(n^k)$. And big-O is math thing, not CS (though, used oftenly in CS).

Comment: If $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$ then $g(n) \in O(f(n))$.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus Perhaps $O(n) = \{1, n\}$ (or even could include non-asymptotic functions like $O(n) = \{.., 1, 0.5n , n, ...\}$ as well)?

Comment: The set $O(n)$ consists of all functions satisfying the definition in Source C.

Comment: You cite three (really, two) sources but none of them contains the (false) statements you (dis)credit to them.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus OK, based on definitions from C roughly $O(n)=\{...,1,...,0.5n,...n\}$ such that all functions in the set have a positive codomain.

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger That's not a definition. It's just a collection of examples. For example, can you tell me whether $e^{\sqrt{\log n}}\in O(n)$ based on the three examples $1$, $0.5n$ and $n$? Heck, could you even tell from those examples whether $2n\in O(n)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first statement you made is not correct. $O(n)$ is the set of all functions $f(n)$ that are bounded above by some constant multiple of $n$ for sufficiently large $n$. The functions you have listed all belong to the set $\Omega(n)$ which is almost like $O(n)$ but instead of being bounded above by $k\cdot n$, this is the set of functions that are bounded *below* by $k\cdot n$ for sufficiently large $n$.

So, there is no contradiction. But you do need to look at your definitions a bit more carefully.

Comment: I misinterpreted the statement "when we say an algorithm is of O(n), it's also O(n^2), O(n1000000), O(2^n)" in source A to mean what I wrote in first bullet point. So indeed C is correct and concrete examples would be $O(n)=\{...,1,...k_{1} \cdot n\}$ and $\Omega(n) = \{k_{2} \cdot n , ...., n^{2}, ....\}$ such that the codomain of all functions in sets are always positive. And as a side note $\Theta(n)=\{k_{1} \cdot n, ..., k_{2} \cdot n\} : k_{1}, k_{2} > 0$.